# How does Amazon calculate the Free Storage Size in a Cloudwatch alarm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have created an AWS Cloudwatch alarm on an RDS HDD available (free) space. Here is my alarm threshold:

> FreeStorageSpace < 69793218560 for 1 datapoints within 5 minutes

If you do the math, this is set to 65GB:

`69793218560 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 = 65`

But Cloudwatch raises an alarm, despite that current free HDD space is ~69.8GB, according to Cloudwatch graph:
[image]

Now, if I do the maths on the value that seems to exceed the threshold:

`69792357581 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 = 64.99`

which is indeed below the threshold, but the graph shows that this is around 69.8.

Is this some bug on Cloudwatch, or perhaps they use some other calculation in the graph?

This is misleading if you make decisions on the thresholds based on the graph values that you see in Cloudwatch, if the graph values are wrong.

Comment: It's hard to tell from that graph, but it seems consistent with G representing 1000^3 as opposed to 1024^3 which you seem to expect. The "G" suffix on its own is amibiguous and could refer to both.